# Resume Feedback

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Has any sort of resume feedback exchange site been considered, possibly as a sub-exchange under 'Programmers'? I've looked around for good feedback locations but the results weren't great (off-shoots of forums that aren't even tech related). As a recent college graduate, I know that my university offers resume feedback (I used it), but they only offer it in the general sense of: spelling, punctuation, spacing, general layout and design, etc.

I was looking more for specified tech feedback from people working/managing in the industry.

Answer (score 22):

As [Anna says](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/resume-feedback/1615#1615), it's possible to post good on-topic questions about resumes here, but you have to make sure it's **not too specific to your situation,** nor too broad to specifically apply to programmers, either.

Many people who do post those kinds of personal questions don't actually realize that their question *can* be extended to apply to many software engineers, **if they just isolated what their *real question* was and left out the superfluous details.**

You just want to fit into the blue range:

[image]

Comment: Love the graphic.

Comment: That would be really useful as part of the FAQ.

Comment: yes, this image should be in the faq, it's fantastic. (perhaps a tad smaller though)

Comment: this is now officially in the [faq]

Answer (score 4):

Resume formatting and style questions are specifically off-topic here, but questions about software development parts of your resume may be okay.

What sort of questions do you have? We can try putting together a question that'd be within the Programmers guidelines.

Comment: I would mainly be looking for feedback in the sense of, as a random example, "Don't include ML in a list of languages you know because it's not used commercially and makes it seem like you're just trying to fill space", or, "Keep ML because it shows... etc". The thing is, I could come up with a list of questions, but it would also just be questions that I already had. Whereas if I could show my full resume, it would allow people to critique me on things I might not have even thought about needing to change.

Comment: @Ryan Answering questions you already have is what Stack Exchange is for.  Open-ended critiques are definitely bad subjective, in addition to the fact that while critiquing your resume may in theory help you, it leaves the site with cruft that will never be referred to by anyone ever again.  Remember, this isn't a forum, we're building a living reference!