# I don't understand why a question of mine has been closed

Tags: support, closed-questions, on-topic-definition

A question of mine has been closed and I really can't understand why, It followed all the guidelines and was very much a real question with a real concern of mine.
[How to keep your eyes on the prize?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86305/how-to-keep-your-eyes-on-the-prize)
It fits all the guidelines: It's definitely a how question, the answer can be as long or short as the answerer wants it to be, I believe my tone was fine (except for the secrecy, I explained that I can't say much about the course itself), it definitely invites sharing experiences - and that is what I was hoping for in an answer, it does not really require references as it's more of a "personal advice" question and I can assure you it is not just mindless social fun.

I was hoping someone can explain to me why it was closed?

I found that most comments did not focus on the question itself but more on the stuff around it, like I initially wrote (by accident) that it takes place in every day of the week, could someone explain to me how to rewrite the question to get more answers of the type I'm asking for?

Answer (score 6):

At first glance it looks like the question could equally apply to any profession.

Take a look at this image (borrowed from [this answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/resume-feedback/1616#1616)):

[image: What's on topic]

Your question fits in the "All Careers" section and is therefore off topic.

We should be asking questions that fit into the blue "All Programmers" section.

Comment: I do believe that my question fits into the programmers section, the alternatives offered were all local to US residents. Where I come from we do not have H&R courses and insurance is sold differently than it is in the US. The field of programming is one of a few (along with medicine and maybe teaching) where this kind of course (and I believe the only one offering that intensity) is something that happens.  
If a closing comes from a localized reason, should it still be closed like localized question are closed and forbidden?

Comment: @Ziv - well raising the issue here on meta is the right thing to do. I'm still not convinced, but if you can get other users to agree the question will be reopened eventually.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure if this was the correct place. Even though I didn't get a really good answer the rest of the answers combined offer a fair answer. I will not try to get it reopened to not sound like an immature kid. I will keep to my moto "Never do things online that you will regret somewhere in the next 40 years".

Answer (score 2):

A good way of understanding this is to substitute every instance of "programmer" and "programming" for "lawyer" or "the practice of law", or "accountant" and "accounting" or "doctor" and medicine.

It's not about whether it applies to programmers, it's about whether it equally applies to a range of other professions.

Comment: +1, but with a caveat: if the question applies to other professions but the answers it'd receive would be significantly different for programmers, then it's fine to ask here.

Answer (score 1):

It's not unique to programmers - as such it's off topic here.

General questions such as this fall outside of the scope here. See [the FAQ on Questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).